# What is the French equivalent of [Today]?

Tags: filter

I'm creating a view in French where it filters on items greater than today's date. Unfortunately, I cannot find the French equivalent for [Today].

Anyone know? Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the [Me] and [Today] filters were localized. Does creating a filter where created by is equal to [Moi] work? If that does, then there should be a proper translation, if not then it might use the English tokens. What is the default site language on this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Aujourd'hui]` should do the trick. Or maybe `[Aujourd’hui]` (mind the apostroph character that may be the wrong in some versions of SP; the best approach would be to copy/paste the exact word from the description).
However, this is only for entering a view condition from the UI, while the page is displayed in French.
If it's about creating and running a CAML query by code, you still use the English version `[Today]`.

Comment: Thanks Evariste. I missed your reply while we were figuring out my issue. I am working through the UI and needed the French equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out, I was spelling aujourd'hui incorrectly! (Missed the u) So yes Eric, you do need to localize the filters and if you spell them correctly they work fine.